# re.sub in Python 3

Tags: python

I have the following types of text

```
1. DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN: | Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 3482 -230 | Pipe: 
2. DIMENSIONS: 2 x 1350 RCP | ORIGIN: PCD13180 | Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 1390 -20800/1350RCP
3. DIMENSIONS: 3 x 375 RCP | Pipe: 35mm | ORIGIN:
4. DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN:
5. Review attribution | DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN:
6. Pipe: | DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN: 2010 PureData Survey
```

REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
1. Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 3482 -230
2. DIMENSIONS: 2 x 1350 RCP | ORIGIN: PCD13180 | Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 1390 -20800/1350RCP
3. DIMENSIONS: 3 x 375 RCP | Pipe: 35mm
4. 
5. Review attribution
6. ORIGIN: 2010 PureData Survey
```

Basically I want to get rid of any blank keys like Dimensions, Origin, Pipe etc.

I think we have to do this separately for each key...I would prefer this as there are lots more keys I need to use it for.

According to https://regex101.com/r/OX1W3b/6

```
(.*)DIMENSIONS:  \|(.*)
```

works but I am not sure how to use it in python

```
import re
str='DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN: | Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 3482 -230'
x=re.sub(".*DIMENSIONS.*","(.*)DIMENSIONS:  \|(.*)",str)
print(x)
```

Results in just a repeat of the 2nd value in re.sub as it is expecting a string and not a regex function.

In Google Sheets I would use `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.*)DIMENSIONS:  \|(.*)")`

Is there something similar in python? Re.sub needs the value to replace with but I am getting this from the regex capture groups.

Note this is similar to my question in [gis se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318774/pyqgis-search-and-replace-text-using-regex) - as it's more of a python question than a gis question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say just split each line on `|` into separate fields, check if there's no value, and then rejoin on `|`:

```
s = '''DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN: | Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 3482 -230 | Pipe: 
DIMENSIONS: 2 x 1350 RCP | ORIGIN: PCD13180 | Position corrected and IL (0) was changed based on RPS: 1390 -20800/1350RCP
DIMENSIONS: 3 x 375 RCP | Pipe: 35mm | ORIGIN:
DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN:
Review attribution | DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN:
Pipe: | DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN: 2010 PureData Survey'''.splitlines()

result = []
for line in s:
    line = line.split('|')
    lst = []
    for field in line:
        if not field.strip().endswith(':'):
            lst.append(field)
    result.append('|'.join(lst).strip())
```

Or, in one line:

```
result = ['|'.join([field for field in line.split('|') if not field.strip().endswith(':')]).strip() for line in s]
```

Note that this gives you a list of lines. You can rejoin them with `'\n'.join(result)` if necessary.

This is the part that parses each line:

```
'|'.join([field for field in line.split('|') if not field.strip().endswith(':')]).strip()
```

For example, if `line` is `DIMENSIONS: 3 x 375 RCP | Pipe: 35mm | ORIGIN:`, that gives us this:

```
DIMENSIONS: 3 x 375 RCP | Pipe: 35mm
```

Comment: thanks -the problem is that it's 1000's of lines in a shp file, so it needs to run line by line. So I just need to figure out how to use the re.sub to find when a key is present without a value and then remove it but retain the rest of the string.

Comment: @GeorgeC - No problem; I'll highlight the part that parses each line for you.

Comment: -so ex, 6 - s='Pipe: | DIMENSIONS:  | ORIGIN: 2010 PureData Survey' and after running the command and using print(''.join(result)) I get
"Pipe|DIMENSIONS|ORIGIN2010PureDataSurvey" --- this is without the : -I should be getting "ORIGIN: 2010 PureData Survey" as both Pipe and Dimensions have no value.

Comment: @GeorgeC - I'm getting the correct result. With that `s`, the result you want would be `result = '|'.join([field for field in s.split('|') if not field.strip().endswith(':')]).strip()`.